# Typescript, Immutable Records, Generics & Type collections

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

**Versions:**

- Typescript 2.8
- Immutable: 4.0 RC.9

I'm trying to create a bunch of model classes, each having some attributes in common. Now i want to create a function that will operate on that common attributes with a generic typed input which takes a instance from any model.

A simple (and working) version:

```
import { Set, Record } from 'immutable';


class Factory {}
class AnimalFactory extends Factory {
  public static x: Set<{ id: string }> = Set([]);
}
class BeastFactory extends Factory {
  public static x: Set<{ id: string }> = Set([]);
}

function getEntityId<T extends keyof TypeMap>(entity: T) {
  const factory = TypeMap[entity];
  factory.x.add({ id: 'id' })
}

type TypeMap = typeof TypeMap;
const TypeMap = {
  a: AnimalFactory,
  b: BeastFactory,
}
```

In `getEntityId` you can see that it accepts `ÀnimalFactory` or `BeastFactory and attributes and methods inside the attributes all infer and merge the types of both classes, so that i can do`factory.x.add({ id: '' })` fully typed. But i could not access a attribute that is only part of a subset of Classes from TypeMap.

Now when I`m trying to apply the same concept on to immutable records, it doesnt work same as in the above example.

Here is the Record example:

```
const animal2Defaults = {
  foo: '',
  x: Set<keyof IAnimalAttributes>([]),
};
export interface IAnimalAttributes {
  foo?: string;
  x?: Set<keyof IAnimalAttributes>;
}

class AnimalFactory2 extends Record<Required<IAnimalAttributes>>(animal2Defaults) {
  public constructor(config: IAnimalAttributes) { super(config); }
}


const beast2Defaults = {
  bar: '',
  x: Set<keyof IBeastAttributes>([]),
};
interface IBeastAttributes {
  bar?: string;
  x?: Set<keyof IBeastAttributes>;
}

class BeastFactory2 extends Record<Required<IBeastAttributes>>(beast2Defaults) {
  public constructor(config: IBeastAttributes) { super(config); }
}

function getEntityId2<T extends keyof TypeMap2>(entity: T, record: TypeMap2[T]) {
  record.x.add('x'); // [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a 
  // call signature. Type '((value: "foo" | "x") => Set<"foo" | "x">) | 
  // ((value: "x" | "bar") => Set<"x" | "bar">)' has no compatible call signatures.

  const unionRecord: TypeMapUnion = record;
  unionRecord.x.add('x'); // [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
  // Type '((value: "foo" | "x") => Set<"foo" | "x">) | ((value: "x" | "bar") => Set<"x" | "bar">)' has no 
  // compatible call signatures.
  // (property) add: ((value: "foo" | "x") => Set<"foo" | "x">) | ((value: "x" | "bar") => Set<"x" | "bar">)

  const injectRecord: AttributeUnionRecords = record; // [ts]
  // Type 'TypeMap2[T]' is not assignable to type 'AttributeUnionRecords'.
  //   Type 'AnimalFactory2 | BeastFactory2' is not assignable to type 'AttributeUnionRecords'.
  //     Type 'AnimalFactory2' is not assignable to type 'AttributeUnionRecords'.
  //       Type 'AnimalFactory2' is not assignable to type 'Record<Required<IAnimalAttributes> | Required<IBeastAttributes>> & Readonly<Required<IBeastAttrib...'.

  if (record instanceof BeastFactory2) {
    record.x.add('x')
  }
}

function createInstance<T extends keyof TypeMap>(entity: T) {
  const instance = new TypeMap2[entity]({}); // [ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
  // (parameter) entity: T extends "a" | "b"
  instance.x.add('x')
}
type AttributeUnion2 = Required<IBeastAttributes>;
type AttributeUnionRecords = Record<Required<IAnimalAttributes> | Required<IBeastAttributes>>
  & Readonly<Required<IAnimalAttributes> | Required<IBeastAttributes>>;
type TypeMapUnion = AnimalFactory2 | BeastFactory2;
type TypeMap2 = {
  a: AnimalFactory2,
  b: BeastFactory2,
};
const TypeMap2 = {
  a: AnimalFactory2,
  b: BeastFactory2,
}
```

The problem I have are the errors that TS is throwing, please see inline comments above for the errors. If you know how to solve it or how to do it differently please let me know.